# Problem with validating a viewmodel using fluent validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, fluent-nhibernate, fluentvalidation

I am trying to validate a viewmodel using fluent validation. When i post the viewmodel object, the modelstate.isvalid always returns false. When i have checked the values on the posted object, the properties which were used to get the data to be shown in dropdowns are also being validated. How to resolve this. Am i doing it in a wrong way, pls help. 
I'm new to ASP.net MVC and just trying out using fluent validation and fluent NHibernate mappings in this project.

More details as follows:

I have a domain model object as below:

```
[Validator(typeof(TestRequirementValidator))]
public class TestRequirement
{
  public virtual int Id { get; private set; } 
  public virtual int SampleId { get; set; }
  public virtual int TestId { get; set; }
  public virtual int StandardId { get; set; }    
  public virtual string Description { get; set; }
  public virtual Sample Sample { get; set; }
  public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
  public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a view model as below:

```
[Validator(typeof(TestRequirementViewModelValidator))]
public class TestRequirementViewModel
{
  public TestRequirement TestRequirement; 
  public SelectList Samples;
  public SelectList Tests;
  public SelectList Standards;

  public TestRequirementViewModel()
  {
    ISession _session = FNHsessionFactory.GetSessionFactory();
    this.TestRequirement = new TestRequirement();
    this.Samples = new SelectList(from S in _session.Linq<Sample>() select S, "Id", "Name");
    this.Tests = new SelectList(from T in _session.Linq<Test>() select T, "Id", "Name");
    this.Standards = new SelectList(from St in _session.Linq<Standard>() select St, "Id", "Name");
  }
}
```

Model Validator is as below:

```
public class TestRequirementValidator : AbstractValidator<TestRequirement>
{
  public TestRequirementValidator()
  {    
    RuleFor(x => x.SampleId)
     .NotEmpty()
     .WithMessage("This field is required")
     .DisplayName("Sample Name");

    RuleFor(x => x.TestId)
      .DisplayName("Test Name"); 

    RuleFor(x => x.StandardId)
      .NotEmpty()
      .WithMessage("This field is required")
      .DisplayName("Standard Name");

    RuleFor(x => x.Description)
      .NotEmpty()
      .WithMessage("This field is required")                
      .Length(0, 10)
      .WithMessage("Length of this field cannot be more than 10 characters");
  }
}
```

View model validator is as below:

```
public class TestRequirementViewModelValidator:AbstractValidator-TestRequirementViewModel-
{
  public TestRequirementViewModelValidator()
  {            
    RuleFor(x => x.TestRequirement)
      .SetValidator(new TestRequirementValidator());   
  }
}
```

View is as below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<foo.Models.ViewModels.TestRequirementViewModel>" MasterPageFile="~/Views/shared/site.master" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" ID="MainContentContent" runat="server">
  <h3><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %></h3>

  <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Create Test Requirement</legend>  

      <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestRequirement.SampleId) %>
      </div>

      <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TestRequirement.SampleId, new SelectList(Model.Samples.Items, Model.Samples.DataValueField, Model.Samples.DataTextField), "Select Sample") %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestRequirement.SampleId) %>
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestRequirement.TestId) %>
      </div>

      <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TestRequirement.TestId, new SelectList(Model.Tests.Items, Model.Tests.DataValueField, Model.Tests.DataTextField), "Select Test") %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestRequirement.TestId) %>
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestRequirement.StandardId) %>
      </div>

      <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TestRequirement.StandardId, new SelectList(Model.Standards.Items, Model.Standards.DataValueField, Model.Standards.DataTextField), "Select Standard") %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestRequirement.StandardId) %>
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestRequirement.Description) %>
      </div>

      <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TestRequirement.Description) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestRequirement.Description) %>
      </div>

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>  
  <% } %>

  <%= Html.ClientSideValidation<TestRequirement>("TestRequirement") %>
</asp:Content>
```

Controller is as below:

```
public ActionResult TestRequirement()
{   
  TestRequirementViewModel NewTestRequirement = new TestRequirementViewModel();
  return View(NewTestRequirement);
} 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestRequirement(TestRequirementViewModel NewTestRequirement)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ISession _session = FNHsessionFactory.GetSessionFactory();    
    _session.SaveOrUpdate(NewTestRequirement.TestRequirement);    

    ViewData["Message"] = "New Test Requirement has been created successfully";

    return View();
  }

  return View(NewTestRequirement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with Fluent Validation, but as you've tagged this as fluent-nhibernate I thought I should comment on your NHibernate usage.

Your view model should not be using NHibernate in its constructor; in fact, your view model should just be a data structure that gets populated by an external service. Similarly, you might want to do the same with your controller; it's common for people to extract data access into a [repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) to isolate their controllers (and make testing easier, you are testing aren't you?).

If you're using a repository, you can then project your view model from your entity; you can do that either by using [NHibernate projections and transformers](http://www.junasoftware.com/blog/nhibernate-setresulttransformer-and-dto.aspx) or by using a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).